# Ошибка при добавлении поста

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Разбираю книгу "Меле А. - Django 2 в примерах", все делал пошагово, настроил файл models.py следующим образом:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)  # поле заголовка статьи
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')  # поле для формирования url
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')  # внешний ключ(один к многим) автор статьи
    body = models.TextField()  # содержание статьи/текст
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)  # дата публикации
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  # дата создания
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)  # дата изменения
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')  # статус статьи

    class Meta:  # класс, содержащий метаданные: порядок сортировки по убыванию даты публикации
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):  # метод __str__ возвращает отображение объекта понятное человеку
        return self.title
```

выполнил миграции, создал суперюзера. И при добавлении поста в админке получаю следующую ошибку:

```py
Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/blog/post/add/
Exception Value: no such table: main.auth_user__old
```

Пробовал удалять базу данных и делать миграции заново, однако не помогло. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: А у Вас именно такие отступы, как в вопросе? Попробуйте класс `Meta` и метод `__str__` перенести в тело класса `Post`.

Comment: перенес, выполнил миграции, ошибка та же осталась

Comment: Какую версию `Django` Вы используете и как именно делаете миграции? Нашёл [тикет](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29182) с похожей ошибкой. Кстати, метод `__str__` должен быть на одном уровне с классом `Meta`.

Comment: поставил метод на один уровень, ошибка осталась. Использую версию 2.0.5. А миграции, захожу в каталог проекта и выполняю команды `manage.py makemigrations` и `manage.py migrate`

Comment: Скорее всего, дело в версии. Попробуйте обновить `Django`, если у Вас есть такая возможность: `pip install -U django`. Это должно решить проблему, если верить тикету, который я привёл выше.

Comment: Я думал об этом, просто книга конкретно на второй версии джанго. Если я поставлю третью, то не будет ли кардинальных изменений?

Comment: Если Вы только изучаете `Django`, то не заметите различий. Советую обновиться. Или можно поставить конкретную версию из ветки 2: `pip install 'django==2.2'`.

Comment: спасибо! Обновил версию, полностью создал проект и приложение заново и заработало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это [ошибка](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29182) `Django`, которая была исправлена в более новых версиях.

Просто обновите framework:

```
pip install -U django
```